# (NODEJS) express global installation not working

Tags: node.js, express

i am new to `node` and `express`

I did install the node and npm on my ubuntu 13.10 machine. Now, I am trying to install `express` globally using the following command (i followed  instructions on [official site](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable) )

```
sudo npm install express -g
```

but when i am trying to do

```
express --help
```

or

```
express
```

It gives nothing back in shell

Following logs printed when doing `sudo npm install express -g`

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No readme data.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
/usr/bin/express -> /usr/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
express@3.2.6 /usr/lib/node_modules/express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── debug@0.7.2
├── commander@0.6.1
├── mkdirp@0.3.4
├── send@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.7.11 (pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.2.0, qs@0.6.5, cookie@0.0.5, formidable@1.0.14, send@0.1.1)
```

Is anything i am misiing ??

**UPDATE**

i am using the `nodejs` version `v0.10.12`

Comment: what is the output of `which express`?

Comment: @Nirkm it is `/usr/bin/express`

Comment: and is that a symlink to something like `../lib/node_modules/express/bin/express`?

Comment: yes!! `/usr/bin/express` is symlink to `../lib/.../express`

now, whats missing then ??

Comment: Also, what do you get for `node --version`?  And are you sure you are using ubuntu 13.10?  That should be released around October 2013

Comment: sorry, i am using the `ubuntu 13.04` and  by doing `nodejs --version` i am getting `v0.10.12`

Comment: what does `node --version` say?  Some distros change the binary name to `nodejs` but scripts oftentimes depend on `node` (due to historical reasons -- `node` was a very old tool before `nodejs` showed up)

Comment: `node --version` doesn't give anything at all.

is this  causing issue to express ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32231/discussion-between-nirk-and-ajduke)

Comment: @Nirk, thanks a lot for support man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quoted by @Nirk user

> Some distros change the binary name to nodejs but scripts oftentimes
>   depend on node (due to historical reasons -- node was a very old tool
>   before nodejs showed up

Did the following manual change in first line of `/usr/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express` file.

from

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

now it is working for me

@Nirk, thanks a lot for support man

Answer (score 12):

You have to run

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

This downloads more stuff and the express command should work thereafter.